# Excel formula to output date excluding weekends

Tags: excel, date, formula

I need an Excel formula that starts with 1/1/2016 and can output the date in dd/mm/yyyy format for the rest of the year excluding weekends.

I did have this: `=WORKDAY.INTL(1/1/2016,365,2)`
but it only outputs 511 which is 25/05/1901 and that is irrelevant for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the fact that you use 1/1/2016 in the formula directly, and it is interpreted as a number instead of a date.

The following setup worked for me:

```
A1 =1/1/2016     B1 =WORKDAY.INTL(A$1, 1, 1)
                 B2 =WORKDAY.INTL(A$1, 2, 1)
                 B3 =WORKDAY.INTL(A$1, 3, 1)
```

(Also note that the last [parameter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-INTL-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), which is 2 in your case, makes Excel assume weekends fall on Sunday and Monday).

Comment: Ok Thanks. I have converted it into a single string `=TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL("01/01/2016",1,1),"dd/mm/yyyy") ` but it just keeps outputting 04/01/2016. Is there a way to make the first 1 auto increment when dragging down the column or do I have to put 1 to 365 in another column and reference that (as that works fine)? Im just trying to keep it cleaner.

Comment: You can use the `ROW()` function for that.

Comment: You are a genius. I did: `=TEXT(WORKDAY.INTL("31/12/2015",ROW(),1),"dd/mm/yyyy")` and it worked like a charm starting from 01/01/2016, exactly how I wanted :)