# Sum only values which fall Monday to Friday

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I receive a statement (as a .xls) each month which list a bunch billable items with an associated date. I want to create a formula (using either `=sum()` or `=sumifs()` to total the billable items, but only those which fall Monday to Friday (i.e., not weekends). Is that possible?

```
              A             B
------+--------------+-------------
   1  |  05/12/2016  |   $10.00
   2  |  06/12/2016  |   $10.00
   3  |  07/12/2016  |   $10.00
   4  |  08/12/2016  |   $10.00        dates are formatted as
   5  |  09/12/2016  |   $10.00              dd/mm/yyyy
   6  |  10/12/2016  |   $10.00
   7  |  11/12/2016  |   $10.00
   8  |  12/12/2016  |   $10.00
------+--------------+-------------
      |     Sum      |   $80.00
------+--------------+-------------
      |     Sum      |
      | (no weekends)|   $60.00
------+--------------+-------------
```

EDIT:
I've just looked closer at the excel doc, and it's actually a datetime field, e.g. 31/10/2016  12:44:00 pm (displayed as 31/10/16 12:44).

I'm also not looking for a formula which works line by line, I'd like something which I can just copy and paste into a single cell at the bottom of the doc each month which examines `A:A`.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31743614/62576) help?

Comment: There is a worksheet function called WEEKDAY that returns the day of the week.

Comment: Did my answer help you, Brad?

Comment: Brilliant @Andrew! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B8,--(WEEKDAY(A1:A8,2)<6))
```

This is a *hack* which behaves like `SUMIF` but lets you use a function in your criteria. Otherwise, you would need to create an auxiliary column with `WEEKDAY` (in C for example) and then use `=SUMIF(C1:C8,"<6",B1:B8)`.

`WEEKDAY` by default returns 1-7 for SUN-SAT. As this doesn't help, you can change the return type to type `2` with the optional second parameter to make the function return 1-7 for MON-SUN, which lets you do the easy `<6` comparison. You can also use type `3`, which returns 0-6 for MON-SUN, and then obviously use `<5` instead.

More about the `--` hack [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function).